# I got TypeError when using Scrapy View

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, screen-scraping, scrapy-shell

I am trying to use `scrapy view https://www.example.com` (not the real link since I am not allowed to disclose it by my job. Sorry.) to debug the link, but then I got this error.

```
2018-11-01 20:49:29 [twisted] CRITICAL: Unhandled error in Deferred:

2018-11-01 20:49:29 [twisted] CRITICAL:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\kerja\hit\python projects\my_project\my_project-env\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1386, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = g.send(result)
  File "d:\kerja\hit\python projects\my_project\my_project-env\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 98, in crawl
    six.reraise(*exc_info)
  File "d:\kerja\hit\python projects\my_project\my_project-env\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 79, in crawl
    self.spider = self._create_spider(*args, **kwargs)
  File "d:\kerja\hit\python projects\my_project\my_project-env\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 102, in _create_spider
    return self.spidercls.from_crawler(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "d:\kerja\hit\python projects\my_project\my_project-env\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spiders\__init__.py", line 51, in from_crawler
    spider = cls(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'start_requests'
'page' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

How to not get that error?

**UPDATE:**

I get that error on one of my Scrapy project but I don't get any error when using my other Scrapy project. It seems to be a problem in the spider.

Comment: BTW, Ms Web Scraping Expert, have you ever checked https://scrapinghub.com/jobs ? :)

Comment: @starrify I've been interested in that for a long time. I was applying once but I didn't get accepted. I would be interested if there is any chance. Do you work there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.**

As mentioned by Elena [in his/her answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53103477/466611), the sample command you gave wasn't quoted. You'll need to properly handle the `&` character (by quoting the command or at least escaping that character) to pass the right URL to Scrapy as an argument.

While this is something that needs to be resolved, I don't think that's the cause of the `TypeError` you currently have.

**2.**

When handling commands like `scrapy fetch` and `scrapy view`, Scrapy would need to initialize a `scrapy.Spider` instance for the task.

During the process, Scrapy would look for a `scrapy.cfg` file at the current path, and:

- Case A: If there is such a file, Scrapy would recognize the project at the current working path, and try loading an existing `scrapy.Spider` class within.
- Case B: If not, which means there's no Scrapy project available, Scrapy would just initialize a default `scrapy.Spider` instance.

According to the log you shared, it's case A you're having.

What's more, when handling a `scrapy fetch` command Scrapy would try overriding the `start_requests` attribute via spider arguments (related code [here](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/06f2db7fd16ff26534c5e6a7d7e2a41a27451ee0/scrapy/commands/fetch.py#L69)). And according to the log you shared, your spider does not accept such an argument.

Thus you may try any of these approaches:

- Proposal A: Change the working directory to somewhere else, where there's no Scrapy project (e.g. `cd /tmp/`). Then retry the same `scrapy fetch` command.
- Proposal B: Properly handle the input arguments (example below), then retry the same `scrapy fetch` command.

In either case, you might need to fix the `scrapy fetch` command as mentioned in #1.

**3.**

Sample code for proposal B above:

```
import scrapy


class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'test'

    def __init__(self, argument_foo, argument_bar, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # handle your argument "foo" and "bar" here
        # e.g. self.xxx = int(argument_foo)
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try to use quotes? Like `scrapy view "https://empireflippers.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=ef_listings_paginated&page=1"`